# Unable to Fetch Dictionary Value in Sitecore NextJs App

Tags: jss, sxa-jss

I am creating a **Sitecore Headless** application using **NextJs** and trying to fetch the **dictionary** value but unable to do so.
Below is the dictionary Item which I have created in Sitecore.

[image]

And Below is the code snippet which i am using.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { dictionaryServiceFactory } from 'lib/dictionary-service-factory';
import {
  Item,
  Field,
  ComponentParams,
  ComponentRendering,
} from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs';

interface Fields {
  Title: Field<string>;
  Description: Field<string>;
  Products: Item[];
  Author: Field<string>;
}

type MultiListProps = {
  rendering: ComponentRendering & { params: ComponentParams };
  params: { [key: string]: string };
  fields: Fields;
  index: number;
  children: JSX.Element;
};

const Default = (props: MultiListProps): JSX.Element => {
  const siteName = 'Headless';
  const dictionaryService = dictionaryServiceFactory.create(siteName);
  const [headingValue, setGallerydValue] = useState<string | null>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    dictionaryService.fetchDictionaryData('en').then(data => {
      console.log("Fetched data:", data); // Log the fetched data
      if (data && data.Heading) {
        setGallerydValue(data.Heading);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="cards">
      <div className="component-title">
      <h1>{headingValue}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Default;
```

I am getting null value on webpage. Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the 'Dictionary Domain' is added in the app settings tag of the specific site config.

Refer:

```
 <app name="oneweb"
        layoutServiceConfiguration="sxa-jss"
        sitecorePath="/sitecore/content/Headless/oneweb"
        useLanguageSpecificLayout="true"
        dictionaryDomain="{3E599B9D-79AC-4D2E-BF4C-399736F8B94F}"
        graphQLEndpoint="/sitecore/api/graph/edge"
        inherits="defaults"
        serverSideRenderingEngine="http"
        serverSideRenderingEngineEndpointUrl="http://localhost:3000/api/editing/render"
        serverSideRenderingEngineApplicationUrl="http://localhost:3000"
    />
```

Snapshot:
[image]

Comment: HI. Kindly add the code with your answer in case of image for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/19/sitecore-headless-development/internationalization-in-the-jss-sample-app-for-next-js.html) is the link, that needs to be followed to get a dictionary using Sitecore Next.js.

On the Next.js component, you need to import next-localization as below

`import { useI18n } from 'next-localization';`

`const {t} = useI18n() || {};`

`<p>Translated text: {t('custom-key')}</p>`

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `lib/dictionary-service-factory`.
2. Make sure your `DictionaryServiceFactory` class looks like this:

```
export class DictionaryServiceFactory {
  /**
   * @param {string} siteName site name
   * @returns {DictionaryService} service instance
   */
  create(siteName: string): DictionaryService {
    return process.env.FETCH_WITH === constants.FETCH_WITH.GRAPHQL
      ? new GraphQLDictionaryService({
          endpoint: config.graphQLEndpoint,
          apiKey: config.sitecoreApiKey,
          siteName: config.jssAppName,
          jssAppTemplateId: '{9ED66404-64C9-4122-90E1-869CB3CEA566}',
          rootItemId: '{your-site-id-from-sitecore}',
        })
      : new RestDictionaryService({
          apiHost: config.sitecoreApiHost,
          apiKey: config.sitecoreApiKey,
          siteName,
        });
  }
}
```

3. Update the `rootItemId` will be the Item ID of your site.